# input:text different positioning in different browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have two textfields inside a div. In Chrome, Opera and Safari, the second textfield is positioned a little bit more left than upper one.
Hovewer in Safari and IE it is positioned just right.

Here is the codepen for you to try :   http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwoKZr

Here is a simple image that shows the problem:[image]

Here is the relevant part:

```
<body style="

    font-size: 14px;">
    <div id="container" class="container_16">
        <div id="mainSection" class="grid_16">
            <div id="newUserBox" style="
    text-align: center;
">

                <input id="userEmail" type="text" style="
    /* text-align: center; */
    width: 300px;

    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
" placeholder="E-Mail"><br>

    <input id="userPass" type="text" style="
    /* text-align: center; */
    width: 300px;
    /* margin-right: 5px; */
    margin-top: 10px;

    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
" placeholder="Password">

    <br>
        <button style="
                width: 324px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                border-radius: 0px;      clear: both;      
                padding: 8px 10px;      border: none;      background-color: #3FC66F;      

                font-size: 20px;      color: #fff;
            ">Log In</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you using a reset stylesheet?

Comment: Remove all white space between `</input>` and `<br>`. While this fixes the issue, I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use `br` to position the `textboxes`

Remove the `br` and apply the following styles

```
#newUserBox{text-align: center;width: 300px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Side note: try not to use inline-styles

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, but why is my code  rendered differently in different browsers?